# Should I use dependency inversion in this case?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-inversion

I have a Document class and a DocumentItem class. A document creates multiple DocumentItems.

As my project has evolved, I realized that DocumentItem needed some "deep" logic to properly display, first checking a database, then the web. My code ended up looking like this:

```
class DocumentItem 
 ...
    function getValue() {
        $du= new DocumentUtils();
        $possibleValue = $du->LookupValueInDatabaseRecursively();
        if (!$possibleValue)
            $possibleValue = $du->LookupValueOnWeb();
        return $possibleValue;
    }
```

What I don't like about this is that my DocumentItem class has to "know" all about DocumentUtils and the deeper logic associated with getting this value.

Is there a way to isolate DocumentItem from DocumentUtils and it's logic?

Should dependency inversion be used here so we don't have a "tree" of dependencies?

Is there a better design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is encapsulation.  Dependency inversion can help you acomplish that but it's only one of many ways.

What strikes me about `getValue()` is that it doesn't seem to use anything from `DocumentItem`.  If that's true it's living in the wrong place.  Methods should live close to what they need.  The logic here boils down to using one of two fucntions on `DocumentUtils` and that decision is based solely on what one of them returns.  Why is `DocumentItem` even involved here?

```
class DocumentUtils {
...
    function getValue() {
        $possibleValue = $du->LookupValueInDatabaseRecursively();
        if (!$possibleValue) {
            $possibleValue = $du->LookupValueOnWeb();
        }
        return $possibleValue;        
    }
}

class DocumentItem {
    private $du;

    public function __construct($documentUtils) {
        $this->du = $documentUtils;
    }

    function getValue() {
        return $du.getValue();
    }
}

//and here's your dependency injection.
$value = new DocumentItem(new DocumentUtils())).getValue();
```

Now `DocumentItem` doesn't have to know how to get this value.  It makes `DocumentUtils` do it which knows more about what's going on here anyway.

I must say, these names are not optimal.  `Document`, `DocumentItem`, `DocumentUtil`? No wonder you're not sure where to put anything.

If a `Document` creates multiple `DocumentItems` maybe it's a `DocumentFactory`.  Maybe a `DocumentItem` is really just a `Document`. Any maybe this thing that is looking up values in the database or the web is your `DocumentGateway`.

Note: you normally wont want to mix construction and use like I did when I made the dependency injection into a one liner.  The whole point is that now the stuff before and after the dot can be seperated.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. To answer, "it doesn't seem to use anything from DocumentItem" - in reality it does - I simplified the code a bit. (Also, the document iterates through its DocumentItems to create a table of values.) "Before and after the dot" ... not sure I fully understand that -- you mean in the last line of your code -- "$value = new DocumentItem(new DocumentUtils())).getValue();"

Comment: I mean `new DocumentItem(new DocumentUtils())` is contruction code.  You'll want that in your `DocumentFactory`.  `getValue()` is 'use' code. you'll want in anything that uses that value. They shouldn't be mixed together because that creates the same hard coding the dependecy injection is trying to avoid.

Comment: Something like DocumentSource might be a better name for DocumentUtils.